# Title in a Beamer Foot note

Tags: beamer, header-footer, footnotes

My title is little lengthy so some part ( the word theory ) hided in the footnote line .

If I include [] this its hided. How to assign separately footnote in every page?

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,enumerate}
\usepackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure,bg=yellow!85!orange}

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\newtheorem{idea}{Proof idea}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\institute[]{\bf \color{teal}{Assistant Professor \\ PG $\&$ Research Department of Mathematics\\ Dwaraka Doss Goverdhan Doss Vaishnav College, Chennai.}}

\title{\bf SOME APPLICATIONS OF FIXED POINT THEORY}
\centering
\date{ FIXED POINT THEORY }
\author {\bf {Mr. P. THIRUMAL} }
```

Comment: Please **(i)** extend your code fragment to complete small document, which we can copy and compile in our computers and which reprosuce your problem, **(ii)** from preamble remove all duplicates and **(iii)** packages, which are leaded by `beamer` (`graphicx`,  `amsmath`,  `xcolor`),  **(iv)** `xcolor` is supersede of `color`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Thank you.

\title[FIXED POINT THEORY]{\bf SOME APPLICATIONS OF FIXED POINT THEORY}

using this I got Title and footnote separately.

Comment: It is worth to read `beamer` package documentation. There is your problem well described as well how to define styles for title frame in presentation. Your approach is not in spirit of `beamer` nor in LaTeX ...